# Sequence-to-sequence classification with variable sequence lengths in Keras

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I would like to train an LSTM or GRU network in TensorFlow/Keras to continuously recognize whether a user is walking or not based on input from motion sensors (accelerometer and gyroscope). I have 50 input sequences with lengths varying from 581 to 5629 time steps and 6 features and 50 corresponding output sequences of boolean values. My problem is that I don't know how to feed the training data to the fit() method.

I know approximately what I need to do: I'd like to train with 5 batches of 10 sequences each, and for each batch I have to pad all but the longest sequence so all 10 sequences have the same lengths and apply masking. I just don't know how to build the data structures. I know that I can make one big 3D tensor of size (50,5629,6) and that works, but it's painfully slow, so I'd really like to make the sequence length of each batch as small as possible.

Here's the problem in code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# Load data from file
x_list, y_list = loadSequences("train.csv")

# x_list is now a list of arrays (n,6) of float64, where n is the timesteps
# and 6 is the number of features, sorted by increasing sequence lengths.
# y_list is a list of arrays (n,1) of Boolean.

x_train = # WHAT DO I WRITE HERE?
y_train = # AND HERE?

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
            tf.keras.layers.Masking(),
            tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences=True),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
        ])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
            loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
            metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=10, epochs=100)
```

Comment: You can try and make some embeddings of fixed size (ex. 500) and feed that into your network

Comment: @Novak I only know embeddings as a sort of feature vector for words in NLP. Can you clarify how that would be useful for feeding sequences of variable lengths into model.fit()? Notice that my problem is not NLP-related.

Comment: Embeddings are mostly used in NLP, but they are used for other stuff as well. There are functions that can create embeddings from arbitrary sequence. Or you can use something like [dimensionality reduction](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/embedding#projections). Either way, goal is to get shorter sequence that preserves the attributes of an object to other objects and that it's mapping with original object is 1-to-1 (every object has a different embedding).

Comment: In Keras, you can use Embedding layer to embed the input data. So, you feed the padded data to the embedding layer and set the dimension of Embedding layer to be 500 - you get 500-long embeddings. Now, you train it and for predict you can use embedding layer weights to embed the input sequences to feed the data to the model.

Comment: My problem is a sequence-to-sequence classification problem, meaning that I need to predict a class for each time step. For example, a (1000, 6) sequence (1000 timesteps, 6 features) of floats should predict a (1000,1) sequence of booleans. Moreover, prediction should work in real time, so it should predict a new boolean for each new incoming 6-feature vector. So I don't think embedding an arbitrary-length sequence into a fixed-size embedding would work here. I'm sorry if my problem description wasn't clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do some thing like this

use generator function take a look at this link [fit_generator](https://keras.io/models/sequential/) look for fit_generator method.

```
def data_generater(batch_size):
print("reading data")
training_file = 'data_location', 'r')

# assuming data is in json format so feels free to change accordingly

training_set = json.loads(training_file.read())
training_file.close()

batch_i = 0  # Counter inside the current batch vector
batch_x = []  # The current batch's x data
batch_y = []  # The current batch's y data

while True:

    for obj in training_set:
        batch_x.append(your input sequences one by one)
        if obj['val'] == True:
            batch_y.append([1])
        elif obj['val'] == False:
            batch_y.append([0])
        batch_i += 1

        if batch_i == batch_size:
            # Ready to yield the batch
            # pad input to max length in the batch
            batch_x = pad_txt_data(batch_x)
            yield batch_x, np.array(batch_y)
            batch_x = []
            batch_y = []
            batch_i = 0

def pad_txt_data(arr):
# expecting arr to be in the shape of (10, m, 6)
paded_arr = []
prefered_len = len(max(arr, key=len))

# Now pad all your sequences to preferred length in the batch(arr)

return np.array(paded_arr)
```

and in the model

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Masking(mask_value=0., input_shape=(None,6)))
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(32))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="softmax"))
model.compile(optimizer="Adam", loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
model.fit_generator(data_generater(10), steps_per_epoch=5, epochs=10)
```

Batch_size, steps_per_epoch, epoch can be different.
Generally

`steps_per_epoch = (number of sequences/batch_size)`

Note: Form reading your description your task appears to be Binary classification problem not like an Sequence to sequence problem. A good example for sequence to sequence is a language translation. Just google around you will find what i mean.

And if you really want to see the difference in training times I suggest using a GPU if available and [CuDNNLSTM](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/CuDNNLSTM).

Comment: Thank you, that works! With regard to what to call the problem, I know what you mean but I was afraid "binary classification" would lead readers to think entire sequences should be classified, rather than outputting a class for each time step. With regard to using CuDNNLSTM, it seems this layer doesn't support masking, am I right?

Comment: unfortunately yes.

Comment: Sorry i mean CuDNNLSTM does not support masking

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps someone, here's how I ended up implementing a solution:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# Load data from file
x_list, y_list = loadSequences("train.csv")

# x_list is now a list of arrays (m,n) of float64, where m is the timesteps
# and n is the number of features.
# y_list is a list of arrays (m,1) of Boolean.
assert len(x_list) == len(y_list)
num_sequences = len(x_list)
num_features = len(x_list[0][0])
batch_size = 10
batches_per_epoch = 5
assert batch_size * batches_per_epoch == num_sequences

def train_generator():
    # Sort by length so the number of timesteps in each batch is minimized
    x_list.sort(key=len)
    y_list.sort(key=len)
    # Generate batches
    while True:
        for b in range(batches_per_epoch):
            longest_index = (b + 1) * batch_size - 1
            timesteps = len(x_list[longest_index])
            x_train = np.zeros((batch_size, timesteps, num_features))
            y_train = np.zeros((batch_size, timesteps, 1))
            for i in range(batch_size):
                li = b * batch_size + i
                x_train[i, 0:len(x_list[li]), :] = x_list[li]
                y_train[i, 0:len(y_list[li]), 0] = y_list[li]
            yield x_train, y_train

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
            tf.keras.layers.Masking(mask_value=0., input_shape=(None,num_features)),
            tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences=True),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
        ])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
            loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
            metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit_generator(train_generator(), steps_per_epoch=batches_per_epoch, epochs=100)
```